# @font-face takes too long to import font

Tags: html, css, import, fonts, font-face

I am quite new on the forum and I am quite a rookie with html and css.

Btw, I am creating a html/css page and I got the external css in which I needed to import a particular font for my page.

Everything is perfectly fine, only the @font-face takes too long to import the font.

This means that when I open the html file (the page is not yet online), the page opens up with the default font and 1sec later it changes the font of the entire page. The transcation of importing is quite easy to see during the opening of the html file.

Is there a way to make the import quicker?

Here's the css with @font-face:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    src: url('font/Montserrat-Regular.eot');
    src: url('font/Montserrat-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('font/Montserrat-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('font/Montserrat-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
        url('font/Montserrat-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('font/Montserrat-Regular.svg#Montserrat-Regular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
}
```

Thanks a lot to everyone

Comment: You should try it on a server, maybe with some kind of CDN... maybe in that case you will get faster result. There is a trick anyway, you can make loading script for your page to hide that style changes from user. just create a loading gif that covers all the page and include at the bottom script that hides loading element. It will be loaded as last script and user will not see anything

Comment: I have not tried it on a server. I mean, right now I can just try with a local one (MAMP), maybe it looks different. Should it not work, I will try to add some loading gif or whatsoever to hide the style cahnges for the first seconds. Thank a lot.